# Multipeer Connectivity: Browsing in Objective-C++ Silently Fails

Tags: macos, objective-c++, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to write the browser/discovery side for a Multipeer Connectivity app in Objective-C++. I think I can advertise, as far as I can tell anyways since I can see it using Discovery (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/discovery-dns-sd-browser/id1381004916?mt=12). But my browser doesn't see anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#import <MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h>

@interface Bowser : NSObject<MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate>

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser 
    foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID 
    withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser 
    lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID;

@end

@implementation Bowser

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser 
    foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID 
    withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser 
    lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
    std::cout << "Goodbye" << std::endl;
}

@end

int main() {
    MCPeerID* peerid = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"PeerId"];
    Bowser* delegate = [[Bowser alloc] init];

    MCNearbyServiceBrowser* browser = [MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc];
    [browser initWithPeer:peerid serviceType:@"m"];

    browser.delegate = delegate;

    [browser startBrowsingForPeers];

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);

    [browser stopBrowsingForPeers];
}
```

Also useful would be suggestions on how to debug what's happening. Anybody...?

Comment: you aren't `init`ing your `MCPeerID `

Comment: @BradAllred True! Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (finally) figured it out. MultipeerConnectivity needs a run loop. This is ***not*** in the documentation.

I assumed that the MultipeerConnectivity API created the threads and/or loops it needed upon the method call `[browser startBrowsingForPeers]`. It does not.

Nowhere in this code is a run loop started. Also, interestingly enough, using a NSThread directly doesn't start a run loop, even though it's [implied that it will](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop?language=objc):

> Your application neither creates or explicitly manages NSRunLoop
>   objects. Each NSThread object—including the application’s main
>   thread—has an NSRunLoop object automatically created for it as needed.
>   If you need to access the current thread’s run loop, you do so with
>   the class method currentRunLoop.

What will create a run loop (and start it) is [`CFRunLoopRun()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542011-cfrunlooprun?language=objc):

> The current thread’s run loop runs in the default mode (see Default
>   Run Loop Mode) until the run loop is stopped with CFRunLoopStop or all
>   the sources and timers are removed from the default run loop mode.

What will stop it, then, is [`CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopRef rl)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1541796-cfrunloopstop?language=objc):

> This function forces rl to stop running and return control to the
>   function that called CFRunLoopRun or CFRunLoopRunInMode for the
>   current run loop activation.

Of course, `CFRunLoopStop` takes a `CFRunLoopRef` as an argument. You can get that by using `CFRunLoopGetCurrent`, just remember it's a reference and may expire at any time. I think you can be pretty sure that the run loop won't die while you're in the callback that's running in the run loop. But I wouldn't count on it sticking around afterwards. In fact, in this case, the whole point is to kill it at this point; so I expect it to go away.